# Manipulating data of file several times

Tags: python, string, list, file

I'm having a little bit trouble with file operations.. I want to manipulate data 2 times and write the last manipulated data into same file.

This is my manipulated file:

```
['Simon', 93.45000000000002, 'AA']
['Jane', 87.55000000000001, 'BA']
['Peter', 85.95, 'BA']
```

And here is my code for how to change data in file.

```
for line in manipulated_file:
    line=line.split()
    list_to_be_written=[]
    for i in line:
        i=i.replace("['","")
        i=i.replace("'","")
        i=i.replace(",",":")
        i=i.replace("]","")
        list_to_be_written.append(i)
    list_to_be_written=" ".join(list_to_be_written)
    print list_to_be_written
```

It runs perfecly how ever i can't write the output to the file..

Expected output in the same file:

```
Simon: 93.45000000000002: AA
Jane: 87.55000000000001: BA
Peter: 85.95: BA
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that if you want your data will be written into the same file as the initial data, you have to open it first for reading, read into variable, process it, then open it for writing and write down everything that is needed. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) for details.

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as manipulated_file:
    manipulated_file_lines = manipulated_file.readlines()
with open("file.txt", "w") as  manipulated_file:

    for line in manipulated_file_lines:
        line=line.split()
        list_to_be_written=[]
        for i in line:
            i=i.replace("['","")
            i=i.replace("'","")
            i=i.replace(",",":")
            i=i.replace("]","")
            list_to_be_written.append(i)
        list_to_be_written=" ".join(list_to_be_written)
        print list_to_be_written

        manipulated_file.write(list_to_be_written)
```

P.S. I'm not sure that you have to process your lines manually in this way. I believe it is better to convert them to Python object (e.g. list) with `json` decoder, then format output string from that object. This can be used instead of those `.replace()`'s:

```
import json
with open("file.txt", "r") as manipulated_file:
    manipulated_file_lines = manipulated_file.readlines()
with open("file.txt", "w") as  manipulated_file:
    for line in manipulated_file_lines:
        processed_list = json.loads(line.replace("'",'"'))
        list_to_be_written=": ".join(map(str,processed_list))
        # this should be tweaked if you want full precision for numbers

        print list_to_be_written

        manipulated_file.write(list_to_be_written)
```

You can also use `ast.literal_eval` instead of `json.loads`, see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval).

Comment: Thanks Ilya that is really helpful for me! :) I'm so new in python so that i don't know a lot about decoder or some other methods .. 
However, i will look at it. Thanks :3

Comment: This won't produce expected result, it will lose precision.

Comment: @AhsanulHaque, I agree, but this can be simply fixed by using appropriate `.format()` method or `%` operator, if it is really needed.

Comment: @IlyaV.Schurov by the way im wondering if is it possible after manipulating data 2 times, changing a unicode in file?

Comment: For example i changed "," 's with ":" but what about changing one of them " ; " and one of them"  : " is it possible @IlyaV.Schurov

Comment: @B.Joelene, I'm not sure I understand what do you want. Could you please post the initial file and the desires result?

Comment: yeah sure  for example: 

Simon: 93.45000000000002: AA
Jane: 87.55000000000001: BA
Peter: 85.95: BA

to

Simon: 93.45000000000002; AA
Jane: 87.55000000000001; BA
Peter: 85.95; BA

in my code i replace all of the commas with ":" is there a way to do this.. @IlyaV.Schurov

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ast.literal_eval`

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open('demo.txt','r') as input_file, open('output.txt','a') as output:
    for line in input_file:
        temp = literal_eval(line)
        output.write(": ".join([repr(a) if type(a)== float else a for a in temp])+'\n')
```

Content of output.txt:

```
Simon: 93.45000000000002: AA
Jane: 87.55000000000001: BA
Peter: 85.95: BA
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` to parse the lists and `fileinput.input` to change the original file.

```
import fileinput
from ast import literal_eval
import sys


for line in fileinput.input("in.txt", inplace=1):
    sys.stdout.write(": ".join(map(str, literal_eval(line))) + "\n")
```

Which will give you:

```
Simon: 93.45000000000002: AA
Jane: 87.55000000000001: BA
Peter: 85.95: BA
```

You can also do it by just splitting and stripping:

```
import fileinput
import sys
for line in fileinput.input("in.txt", inplace=True):
    sys.stdout.write(":".join([w.strip("'") for w in line.strip("[]\n").split(", ")]) + "\n"
```

Which gives you the same output:

```
Simon: 93.45000000000002: AA
Jane: 87.55000000000001: BA
Peter: 85.95: BA
```

If the code happened to error you would lose data so a better option may be to write to a `tempfile` and then  do a `shutil.move`:

```
from shutil import move
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

with open("in.txt") as f, NamedTemporaryFile("w", dir=".", delete=False) as tmp:
    for line in f:
        tmp.write(": ".join([w.strip("'") for w in line.strip("[]\n").split(", ")]) + "\n")

move(tmp.name,"in.txt")
```

Comment: @PadraicCunnigham .. a silly question, is `stdout` always directed to a file?..how do you make sure of that?

Comment: I think you will lose precision in float to str conversion.

Comment: @AhsanulHaque, If you look at the OPs values  I don't think that is something they are worrying about.

Comment: @IronFist, fileinput hogs stdout so every print or stdout write gets directed to the file

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, I don't know if the precision is important or not, but  I commented just because you claimed the code will produce the below output, which is wrong and can create confusion.

Comment: @AhsanulHaque, that is exactly what it produces in python3 so there is no confusion. You can format it to whatever precision you want in pytonn2

Comment: Haha thanx guys for all your help and comments. I need study hard to code like this:3. Using replace is not efficent when you don't want to change all "," 's or else.. is there any way to use replace method just for a specific character which appears many times in line, .. @PadraicCunningham

Comment: @B.Joelene, really how you store you data is key, if you store it in a manner that is easy to parse like a comma separated csv life will be much easier, how did you get the file into the format it is?